# Use fluent to configure EF Core properties on entities of a certain type

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, fluent

I have a bunch of entities which I want to have fields `InsertDate` and `UpdateDate`, with (SQL) default values of `GETDATE()`.

To that end, I made a simple class `AuditableEntity` which a bunch of my entities derived from that looks basically like this:

```
public class AuditableEntity
{
    InsertDate { get; set; }
    UpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

and sample entity like

```
public class Customer : AuditableEntity
{
    CustomerId int { get; set; }
    // etc..
}
```

Then when I'm configuring the entities using the fluent API, I can do something like:

```
public class CustomerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(e => e.InsertDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
        builder.Property(e => e.UpdateDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
    }
}
```

So far, so good.

Except I have a bunch of these `AuditableEntities`, each of which needs those same two property definitions set up.

Is there some central place I can build properties for all Entity which are subtypes of `AuditableEntity`? I tried something like the following, but it fails because it looks like it's trying to instantiate a `DbSet<AuditableEntity>` when all I want to do is to add an identical property to all entities of type `AuditableEntity`.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<AuditableEntity>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.InsertDate)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
            entity.Property(e => e.UpdateDate)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
        });
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(MyContext).Assembly);
    }
    /* When I try to run add-migration with this in here, it says:
     * system.InvalidOperationException: A key cannot be configured on 'DatasetSource' because it is a derived type. The key must be configured on the root type 'AuditableEntity'. If you did not intend for 'AuditableEntity' to be included in the model, ensure that it is not referenced by a DbSet property on your context, referenced in a configuration call to ModelBuilder, or referenced from a navigation on a type that is included in the model.
     */
```

Comment: BTW, you should not be using `GETDATE()` because of 2 reasons: First: it uses the older and less-precise `datetime` type (instead of `datetime2(7)`, and secondarily (but most importantly): it returns the server's **own local time** instead of UTC (so your data will be affected (if not corrupted) by daylight savings and/or moving your SQL Server database to a box in another timezone. It is extremely important that you should only store UTC values in a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1;

The fluent API helps you configure each `IMutableEntity`. But you could do that yourself;

```cs
foreach (var table in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()){
    if (table.ClrType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(AuditableEntity))){
        foreach(var p in table.GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.Name == nameof(AuditableEntity.InsertDate) || p.Name == nameof(AuditableEntity.UpdateDate)))
            p.SetDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
    }
}
```

You can work out what other fluent api calls actually do by reading the [source code on github](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/be3f34c44e7b5f596b54373aeedaf804dbce4e3a/src/EFCore.Relational/Extensions/RelationalPropertyBuilderExtensions.cs#L391).

Option 2;

Write a generic method and manually call it from each of your `IEntityTypeConfiguration` implementations.

```cs
public void ConfigureAuditing<T>(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
    where T:AuditableEntity
{
    builder.Property(e => e.InsertDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
    builder.Property(e => e.UpdateDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
}

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder){
    ConfigureAuditing(builder);
}
```

Option 3;

Combine a little of both approaches. Using reflection and a generic method to call the fluent API;

```cs
public void ConfigureAuditing<T>(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    where T:AuditableEntity{
    var builder = modelBuilder.Entity<T>();
    // as above
}

var method = new Action<ModelBuilder>(ConfigureAuditing<AuditableEntity>)
    .Method
    .GetGenericMethodDefinition();

foreach (var table in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()){
    if (table.ClrType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(AuditableEntity))){
        method.MakeGenericMethod(table.ClrType)
            .Invoke(null, new object[] { modelBuilder });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try these out. Ty